# in python how add text and forward multipart email.message

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtplib

I have `email.message.Message` object and I want to forward it with text that I add as a new mail.
how can I create a new `email.message.Message` that represent the forwarded mail?

I tried to add text to the first part in the multipart but it made the mail unreadable.

should I add new payload to the multipart? should I change any other part?

for example:

```
This is the original mail, might be html or rich-text
```

I want to send like that:

```
This is text I added while forwarding

From: בלה בופ <blah@bop.com>
Sent: Monday, 25 November, 2019 2:02 PM
To: elisha@stackoverflow.com
Subject: example :)

This is the original mail, might be html or rich-text
```